# Checkboxlist selected values to integer array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, checkboxlist

I have a checkboxlist and I want to get the selected checkbox values to an integer array.

my checkboxlist code is

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="chklstBackup" CssClass="question-wrapper" RepeatLayout="UnorderedList">

                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">SkyDrive</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Google Drive</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Own FTP server</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Database (fx MongoDB)</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="5">Local on pc/mac</asp:ListItem>

                </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

I want to get the selected values from this checkbox list to an integer array.

by my code I only getting the values as string.
my code is

```
    List<string> selectedSolution = chklstBackup.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
   .Where(li => li.Selected)
   .Select(li => li.Value)
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<int> selectedSolution = chklstBackup.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
   .Where(li => li.Selected)
   .Select(li => int.Parse(li.Value))
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are getting List. Change it to List and then cast in your select. Something like this should work for you

```
List<int> selectedSolution = chklstBackup.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
   .Where(li => li.Selected)
   .Select(li => int.Parse(li.Value))
   .ToList();
```